# Error with Devise

Tags: ruby, devise

getting an error when trying to load a page but I know entire installation was done correctly
help , here is the error message What is highlighted is the error i'm getting

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

BTW, this was the error i kept getting

```
undefined method `devise' for #<Class:0x00000101f11f10>

Extracted source (around line #4):
```

Comment: Is that a duplicate in your code or was it just a copy-paste error with `devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable`?

Comment: paste error it does come up that many times, here it is corrected: undefined method `devise' for #<Class:0x00000101f11f10>

Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4
5
6
7
          
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
        # :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model